# Improve query with table joins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to retrieve a list of all Downloads as a result of a particular users content. For example, If I have 2 uploads, I want to filter the contents of the Download table to show only those downloads related to *my* Uploads.

```
Users {
    user_id: integer
}

Upload {
    upload_id: integer
    user_id: integer (FK)
}

Download {
    download_id: integer
    upload_id: integer (FK)
}
```

The downloads table is a log of every public user that has downloaded a file ("upload") on my blog.
As you can see, an Upload  is linked to a user (user can have many uploads) and a download is linked to an upload (one upload can be downloaded many times).

This is the solution I am using so far (it's really messy and probably very inefficient):

```
@user = User.find_by_id(3)
# grab a list of the User 3's upload ids, e.g. [3, 6, 2, 34, 45]
@upload_ids = @user.uploads.map { |u| u.upload_id }

# now find all Downloads that have these id numbers in their upload_id
@downloads = Download.where(:upload_id => @upload_ids)
```

I'm sure there is a way to achieve this with table joins.
UPDATE: All associations are explicitly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the associations are explicitly configured, you can use something like:

```
Download.joins(:upload).where("uploads.user_id = ?", 3)
```

You can already improve your query by making some assumptions:

1. You don't need to fetch the user
2. Use `pluck` instead of mapping over the ids

Here's an example of using 2 optimized queries with no JOIN:

```
@downloads = Download.where(upload_id: Upload.where(user_id: 3).ids)
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I'm looking for!!

Comment: Is that as optimised as it gets? I mean a list of id numbers in the IN clause of the SQL staement?

Comment: My first statement runs in 1 query, the second in 2 queries. Yours in 3. Moreover, my statements use a `SELECT id` whereas yours a `SELECT *`. Last but not least, mine uses `pluck` to avoid instantiating the unnecessary `Upload` records.

Comment: That's awesome. :) Yeah, mine was in no way efficient. That's why I asked the question. Thanks for the extra explanation :) Which one of your statements should I use? Is the join statement better because it runs in 1 query? (I've heard joins can be inefficient)